# How to run Apache Zeppelin 0.9.0 and Apache Spark 3.1.1 if they are not compatable?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

So I'm trying to use Apache Zeppelin but it out puts the following error

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open SparkInterpreter
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:836)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open SparkInterpreter
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:122)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: This is not officially supported spark version: 3.1.1
You can set zeppelin.spark.enableSupportedVersionCheck to false if you really want to try this version of spark.
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:112)
```

I'm not sure how to set zeppelin.spark.enableSupportedVersionCheck to false. Also, I'm not sure if I should, as the Zeppelin documentation explicitly states 'Do not change - developer only setting, not for production use'

But I'm not how else to make these compatible without uninstalling my current version of Apache spark and replacing it with an older version, which I really don't want to do.

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: strikes me u cannot

Answer (score 4):

The only way to run it (I am running version 3.1.2) is to disable that check. I found that after that, Zeppelin runs fine with Spark in YARN client mode. For some reason, I can't get it to work in cluster mode. You might want to run it in some other configuration. In any case, the steps to change the option are below.

To make the change:

1. Go to the top right side of the Zeppelin site, there should be a username displayed there. Click on it.
2. Select `Interpreter` in the menu.
3. Search for the `spark` interpreter.
4. Click on `edit` on the right corner.
5. Uncheck `zeppelin.spark.enableSupportedVersionCheck`.
6. Scroll all the way down and hit `Save`.

I hope it works for you!